# How can I find time difference between two server timestamps?

Tags: bash, shell, date, math, time

This outputs the closest Google server's time:

```
// Closest Google Server:
date +"%s" -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
// Result: 1234
```

This outputs my local server time:

```
// Server
date +"%s"
// Result: 1235
```

How can I fetch the seconds between each result? (in the example above: 1)

Comment: What's the output of the two date commands?

Comment: Ok, let me try again.  Put the output of the two date commands in the question.  Basically, you're going to have to covert the output to timestamps, calculate the difference, and throw an error if the difference is more than 10 seconds, say.

Comment: We'll all assume you know how to do math. I think what you meant to ask is "How do I convert these timestamp formats into UTC/GMT?" So, that begs the question, are `1234` and `1235` really what's returned?

Comment: :) No, `1234` was not really returned. I just kept it simple for easy visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly answering your question, how about:

```
echo $(( $(date +"%s") - $(date +"%s" -d "`curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g'`") ))
```